# php if statement doesn't look the second parameter if first valid

Tags: php

I have noticed that PHP doesn't run the second or other parameters of 'if statement' if the first parameter true.

```
if($this->sessions->remove("registered_id") or $this->sessions->remove("user_id")){
        echo "you have logged out";
}else {
        echo "wth?";
}
```

This how I use the if. Also here is the remove function from sessions class.

```
public function remove($key){
        if(isset($_SESSION[$key])){
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The thing that I want to do is run both of this parameters.. I hope I can tell the problem..

Comment: So you want to run the `if` and the `else`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Nope, I want to remove registered_id and user_id at same time without using the if one within the other..

Comment: PHP (and most languages for that matter) will only evaluate the clauses in your `if` condition until it finds one that passes if you are using `or`. Once it finds one that passes, it is unnecessary to evaluate anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to execute both functions, store their respective results, then test on these results.

```
$resultA = $this->sessions->remove("registered_id");
$resultB = $this->sessions->remove("user_id");

if ($resultA or $resultB)
{
     …
```

It's by design that the second statement is not executed, because its result will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If by other parameters you mean the second condition, then use an AND instead of OR

If by other parameters you mean the else, then use a separate if statement instead.

**edit**

If you're trying to execute both statements, use bitwise operators, check out this manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Something like:

```
if(a | b){

}
```

That will execute both a and b, but still is an 'or' comparison.

Comment: But It's registered_id may be empty. Then i need to use or.. You couldn't understand what I'm telling..

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understand what you were trying to do at first. I've edited the post with hopefully what you're looking for. (bitwise exclusive or)

Comment: Using bitwise operators to prevent short circuiting is basically just asking to confuse yourself later.  :P  If you want to evaluate both expressions, then simply make them separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

That result is to be expected. This is what [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) do.

You would need to use `&&` or `and` to achieve what you seem to be looking for:

```
if ($this->sessions->remove("registered_id") && $this->sessions->remove("user_id")) {
```

Here is why:

The `&&` or `and` keyword means that all evaluations must return true. So:

```
if ($a && $b) {
    // $a and $b must both be true
    // if $a is false, the value of $b is not even checked
}
```

The `||` or `or` keyword means that either evaluation must return true. So:

```
if ($a || $b) {
    // Either $a or $b must be true
    // If $a is false, the parser continues to see if $b might still be true
    // If $a is true, $b is not evaluated, as our check is already satisfied
}
```

So in your case, if the `$this->sessions->remove("registered_id")` successfully did it's thing, the `$this->sessions->remove("user_id")` is never called, as our check is already satisfied with the outcome of the first call.